# ReactJs.Net, Gulp, Babel, Browserify MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

My brain hurts, I have just read loads of different tutorials and they seem to differ (or change quite rapidly) in their ideas of how to make this work.

Background:

I have started learning ReactJs.NET, and I would like to start writing ES2015 and using the `Require('SomeComponent')` statement to import modules (babel doesn't import/export yet).

I had this working fine for the ES2015 part, by using a `BabelBundle` that comes with React.NET

```
bundles.Add(New BabelBundle("~/bundles/main").Include(
                "~/Scripts/test.jsx"
            ))
```

I wanted to use some extra components for a project (a multiselect), and it seemed the simplest way to get this and use it was to install node + npm, and then use `require` to import that component.

That led me onto replacing the MVC bundling with gulp, and using a gulpfile to transform/combine my files into a single useable js file (which works better than .NET bundling if I am pre-rendering the first view on the server side anyway).

What I need to do in my gulpfile.js, but I am not 100% sure in which order I need to do it, or how exactly I should describe this in my gulpfile:

- Start with a .jsx file, and then: (not quite sure in which order)
- Parse it with react (fos jsx)
- Parse it with babel (for ES2015 syntax)
- Parse with browserify for (`require` tags)

Am I even going down the right path? there seems to be so many options and I am getting quite confused by them all and what seems to be a rapidly changing landscape..

Comment: I've created a Reactjs.Net Boilerplate example on Github. Admittedly it's not using Gulp as per your question but hopefully it can give some pointers to start with. It will also give you an idea how to create an isomorphic SPA app using react-router if you're interested.

Take a look and see if it's maybe what your looking for? I'd be interested to hear any feedback too :)

https://github.com/imamark/React.Net-Router-Redux

Comment: Looks interesting, but I can't bring myself to go look at another option right now, iill take a look at home, using vs 2013 in work anyway and it's missing some reqs for this

Comment: **sigh** I get the feeling I should probably be going this way, especially when trying to pre-render on the server using the .NET lib :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Intro

> My brain hurts [...] there seems to be so many options and I am getting quite confused by them all and what seems to be a rapidly changing landscape..

That is called "JavaScript fatigue". It is a common affliction.

> Am I even going down the right path?

While all humans must grapple with this existential question, studies show that JavaScript developers are 110% more vexed by it. Food for thought if you decide to continue down this path.

> `Require('SomeComponent')`

`require()` (lower case).

> babel doesn't import/export yet

With the appropriate plugin / preset Babel does compile ES2015 module syntax (`import|export`) to various ES5 module systems, including Node's `require()`. However, you may be better of just using the Node module system for now.

> Parse with browserify for (`require` tags)

`require()` calls -- it's a function, not a tag.

## How to

You don't necessarily need gulp at all for this. Here's a basic example of how to get off the ground with this with Browserify:

```js
var babelify = require("babelify");
var browserify = require("browserify");
var fs = require("fs");

function bundle () {
  return browserify("./entry-module", {
    // Enable source maps for development
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  })
  .transform(babelify, {
    presets: ["es2015", "react"]
  })
  .bundle()
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./bundle.js", "utf8"));
}
```

This will run Babel (via Babelify), and configure it to process ES2015 syntax and JSX. You could put the Babel configuration in a `.babelrc` file instead and just have `transform(babelify)`.

Browserify transforms are run before parsing for `require()` calls. So by the time Browserify needs to analyze the code it'll be ES5.

By default your JSX containing files can be `.js` or `.jsx`.

FWIW the `es2015` preset will compile `import|export` to Node modules.

If you want to integrate with gulp, then you can do something like:

```js
gulp.task("bundle", bundle);
```

## Conclusion

> Am I even going down the right path?

There are many paths. But using Babel is part of the path many successfully take. So is using Browserify (but, for example, some prefer Webpack). If you start with something like what I've illustrated it should get you  off the ground and it should seem much more approachable at that point.

You could also check out my [miniminirepro/babelify](https://github.com/miniminirepro/babelify/tree/api) repo. It's meant as a template for people to create minimal reproductions of bugs, but it serves as a hello world level example of how to bundle with Browserify and transform with Babel.

Comment: Awesome, this seems like the answer I needed - I saw you could run babel as a browserify plugin, but calling browserify from gulp using babel as a plugin just seemed to fry my brain!

Comment: That's done the trick - thankyou very much (also for the reassuring comments that i'm not the only one who feels like this!)

Comment: Great, thanks. Yes, you are by no means the only one that feels that way, FWIW.

Comment: Lol and after all that, I feel webpack may be the way to go! Fun times, but that really helped me anyway so thanks, really I just want to write some bloody code now lol!